# Get rid of dip in shirt

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I'm making a corset kind of thing and was using a mesh I downloaded. When I look at it in Object mode, there is this strange indentation slit. I want it to be flat, not have a strange indent.

But when I go into edit mode, the mesh looks fine, it doesn't look like there is anywhere I need to pull some vertices or edges out. Why is this problem there in Object mode and how do I get rid of it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Oh gee, I figured it out. There was an extra edge in the back of the dip. The inside of the corset had some faces removed, but the ones kept were pulled back into the body so when looking down the corset you don't see space, you only see the edge of the corset. Must have happened when I was mirroring it in building. Maybe an extra edge snuck in there. Here is a view from the inside of the mesh, it was an extra edge. I selected it to be visible.

[image]